# CaptureBitmap function in QTP not working

Tags: qtp

All that I want to do is to take screenshot of a webtable !!

I have done this a million times before and it has worked a million times perfectly.

Line of code is :

```
Browser("name:=IE.*").Page("micclass:=Page")..WebTable("class:=DataTable").CaptureBitmap  "c:\test.png",true
```

But from the past few days , when i execute this line of code.
In the screenshot , instead of the webtable , a white patch appears.

Has anyone experienced this problem ?

If anyone can suggest a solution for this problem it would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: There are two dots between the `Page` and the `WebTable` I assume that's a typo in the question and not related to the issue. What has changed in the last few days? Have you installed a patch or changed browsers?

Comment: Are you using a dual-display config?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem: the bitmap captured is whatever is visible on the screen at the time of the snapshot.  For example, if the QTP window is on top when that script line is hit, I'll get a picture of that, rather than of the browser window.

If that's not what's going on, I'd look at whether your web page has more than one table with class = "DataTable", though you'd probably get a "script error".